# PHP This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: php

I' am working on a custom website. After successful login this is the condition below is run when user is successfully logged in which will redirect user to dashboard. Else if the session is not isset then it will redirect to admin page. I' am getting error on the screen "PHP This webpage has a redirect loop" But when I uncomment this code below everything works fine.

**security.php**

```
<?php
/*
    CHECK FOR ANY SESSIONS
*/
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['session_id'])){

         $session_id = $_SESSION["session_id"];

            header("Location: /admin/dashboard");
            exit();

    } else {
        header("Location: /admin");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

I have tried "ob_start" but no luck at all...

Comment: Add `session_start();` at the top of the page and assign that `$session_id` variable to the session.

Comment: `$session_id = $_SESSION["session_id"];` - what is the purpose of this line?

Comment: hi Dainis Abols, I' am already using session_start() thanks!

Comment: Is there in /admin or in /admin/dashboard the possibilty that you will be redirected back to security.php?

Comment: Are you looking for the SID constant? That'd be enough to check for php's session id.

Comment: hi zerkms, That line assigns the session id to a local variable.

Comment: @Navneil Naicker: great. What for?

Comment: May your /admin code is redirecting to /admin/dashboard/ ? Show /admin code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the `/admin/dashboard` pass trough the `security.php` 
wont it forever set `header("Location: /admin/dashboard");` ?

Comment: Why? Location: /admin/dashboard will redirect you normally to /admin/dashboard/index.php - if in this index.php is no back redirection to security.php everything is fine.

Comment: That is why the 'if' is for I do not know if his admin/dashboard/index.php runs trough his security.php

Comment: hi Sentinel, You were right. I' am including "security.php" in all the scripts, thats why the condition keep looping and giving error. WOW thanks so much you are awesome!

Answer (score 3):

This message probably means that there is a redirect from either /admin/dashboard or /admin back to your script. This will throw your script into a loop.

Check these scripts for possible redirects.